# How to specify ivy version in sbt?

Tags: sbt, ivy

I am using sbt-0.13 which uses ivy-2.3. I have encounter a bug which has been fixed in ivy-2.4. Now I want to update ivy to 2.4.

How to configure sbt so as to make it use ivy-2.4?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the answer to this definitively, but after 30 min of searching, I think the answer is that you can't do this without building your own version of sbt.

The principle evidence I have for this is this change to sbt itself in order to upgrade the version of ivy: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1040.